# Qt OpenGL - Translucent objects show content from behind window

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using Qt5 and its OpenGL integration, and am running into a problem when I try to draw translucent objects. When an object is translucent, whatever is visible behind my OpenGL window is shown within the screen area of that object, instead of the object being blended with whatever is already in the colour buffer. I have started watching YouTube videos through my translucent objects, as whatever shows through is live.

[image: Translucency]

Interestingly, the most see-through an object gets seems to occur at half opacity - full opacity renders it solid, while zero opacity renders nothing at all (and whatever was previously in the background of the 3D scene remains there). Rendering translucent objects last does not fix the issue.

I have noticed that this also happens when I enable mipmaps on my textures - as the distance to a point on an object increases, the pixel concerned becomes more translucent and displays whatever is behind the OpenGL window. The issue occurs both on my Windows and OSX machines.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? Google hasn't proven too helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hah, that's a funny one. I can't tell you what is going on, because it normally takes some extra effort to make windows actually transparent; in Windows you have to select a framebuffer format with an alpha channel and call DwnEnableBlurBehindWindow to actually achieve this effect. And as far as I know Qt doesn't do this.

But if it does here are a few hints:

- Make sure you clear your framebuffer to alpha=1
- When rendering translucent objects keep the destination alpha value 1, i.e. don't use blending modes and functions that modify the destination alpha value, or force it to 1.

There's actually little use for the alpha channel on the main window framebuffer, except for implementing window translucency effects. Unless you need those you should choose an either pixel format without an alpha channel for your window framebuffer, or keep all its pixels alpha values at full opacity.

Comment: You were right about the pixel format - I was setting the default format to use an 8-bit alpha buffer and was also outputting colours from my fragment code with whatever alpha value was input. It looks like this was setting the alpha value of the window frame buffer, which meant things from behind showed through. Am I right in thinking this means the OpenGL blend function only uses the input alpha to calculate the end RGB colour, and so I don't need to write that alpha from the fragment shader?

Comment: @x6herbius: You can configure how OpenGL used both the source (incoming pixel) and destination (what's already in the framebuffer) alpha values using `glBlendFunc` or `glBlendFuncSeparate` – it's perfectly possible to use destination alpha for calculations as well. But cases where using this on the main framebuffer are rare (it makes sense off-screen though for creating intermediary images).

Comment: This saved my life. In main, before creating the application, I was setting setAlphaBufferSize(8), this was making the window itself transparent. The solution was to remove the line:

[code]
  QSurfaceFormat formato;
  formato.setAlphaBufferSize(8);  // <- dont do this.
...
  return formato;
[/code]

And yes, transparency still work inside the OpenGL context of the window.